# Delphi code fails at 64 bits access violation

Tags: delphi

This Delphi code works when compiled for 32 bits, but gives an access violation when compiled for 64 bits. Is there a problem with the code, or is there a compiler bug?

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

const
  MaxSize = 2; // nothing special about this value, could equally be 1

type
  TArraySize = 1..MaxSize;

procedure Main;
var
  size: TArraySize;
  arr: array [-MaxSize..MaxSize] of Integer;
begin
  FillChar(arr, SizeOf(arr), 0); // zero initialize
  size := MaxSize;
  Writeln(arr[-size]);
end;

begin
  try
    Main;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: It gives AV exactly at the start when Kernel.Size = beMaxGaussKernelSize

Comment: David this code works at 32 bits, I thought there is an evident reason why it should not work in 64bits, that I cannot see

Comment: I thought this piece of code is sufficient

Comment: It would be easy to make a [mcve] so that we don't need to piece it together. Imagine if we could just paste a complete program into our editor? That would require no effort from us.

Comment: I do not argue, but the AV should not happen in this code. The array is enough big to hold the indexes it is passed

Comment: Sure. But why make others do that extra work. I turned your snippets into a [mcve]. This makes a huge difference for people answering.

Comment: Note that I have now simplified the code even further. This is a really important skill to learn. By doing this you narrow the focus for anyone looking at the problem. Not least of which is yourself. Had you done this yourself and ended up with code like this it would have taken you to the specific point where the compiler is defective.

Comment: Which version of Delphi did you discover this problem in?

Comment: Delphi XE2 (without debugger for 64 bits)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a compiler bug. The compiler does not handle

```
arr[-size]
```

correctly, presumably because `size` is a subrange type.

You can workaround the bug by forcing the compiler to perform the arithmetic in an `Integer` context.

```
arr[-Integer(size)]
```

You should submit a bug report to Embarcadero's Quality Portal.

**Update**

I tested this in XE7. According to a comment, the defect appears to have been fixed at least in Seattle.

Comment: Thanks , that was it!...but for my eyes was completely impossible to detect. I have to say this was not my code, or I would have coded it differently

Comment: Your mcve works fine in Seattle, 32 and 64 bit.  Which version did you test this in?

Comment: @J... I used XE7 to test this

Comment: Then probably no need for QP as it seems fixed at least in D10.

Comment: @J... The bug report has value for future readers that are still using older versions

Comment: Fails in XE4 too. In XE2, it doesn't even run, it immediately gives a "disconnected session" from the debugger. Without debugger, it reports an AV too. No problems under Win32 in either of them.

Comment: FWIW, the error seems to be that the 64 bit code sets RAX to 2, then negates *EAX*, which makes RAX $00000000FFFFFFFE, not $FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE. Then it accesses [RBP+4*RAX+$2C]. RAX is not -2, so that goes terribly wrong. Later versions insert a MOVSXD RAX,EAX, which sign expands EAX into RAX, so it becomes -2.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler which gives a Access Violation-error is always having a bug. A compiler should never do that but handle every occurring error gracefully.